# Qt map signal from multiple senders to a single slot

Tags: qt

I sure this can be done, and I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I can'y figure it out.

I have a QList of pointers to a `device_connection class:`QList`.

The QList is owned by my `Device_manager` class.

What I wish to have is is the following:

`QObject::connect(what_to_put_here, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(device_connected()))`,

i.e., I wish to map all the signals emitted by any of the `device_connection`s, to the `device_connected` slot of the `Device_manager` class, while knowing which `device_connection` emitted the signal.

Can this be done?
If so, how do I formulate the `QObject::connect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect a whole list at once. But you can do a loop over the list to connect all elements individually. You can then use `QObject::sender()` within the slot to determine which object emitted a signal.

Alternatively with C++11 and up, you can use a lambda to extend your connection with a pointer to the sender. Your slot would have an extranous argument:

```
void device_connected(device_connection* connection);
```

Then you connect like this:

```
connect(elem, &device_connection::connected, this, [this,elem] {
    device_connected(elem);
});
```

Note that while specifying a receiver object (third argument, `this`) is not mandatory when connecting to a lambda, you should still do it. It will ensure that the connection is cleaned up when the (implicitely) receiving object is deleted.

Comment: Will I run into problems if a second signal is emitted before the first call to the slot is completed, or does the event loop protect me from this?

Comment: Is your application multithreaded? In a single thread, what you describe should not happen. In a single thread, signals lead to direct slot calls (no event loop involved) if you do not explicitely use a Queued Connection. The only way a new signal could be called while in a slot would be if the slot itself triggers the signal (e.g. by making the sender object emit the signal again).

Comment: In a multithreaded scenario, a signal can be delivered through the event loop. In this case also a slot is not interrupted by a new signal; new signals are enqueued in the receiver's thread event queue and processed whenever the thread becomes idle or explicitely processes the event loop. In Qt every object is assigned to a thread and that thread alone processes incoming signals in a serial manner.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Each of my device connection runs a separate thread as communication with them may involve blocking operations

Comment: Qt signals/slots are a convenient and safe way of communication between threads. The typical approach would be to move the device connection objects explicitely to their corresponding QThreads. As I pointed out the receiving object should always be specified when connecting a signal to a lambda slot; this ensures also that the slot is called in the thread of the receiving object.

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra arguments to your signal and slot, and loop over the `QList<device_connection class *>` to connect each element to a `device_connected(device_connection class *)` slot of your `Device_manager` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    connect(list.at(i), SIGNAL(connected(device_connection class *)),
            this, SLOT(device_connected(device_connection class *)));
```

From there you can distinguish the device from the pointer value passed to the slot with `emit connected(this)` from `device_connection class`.

Instead of a pointer and according to what you need to do in your `device_connect` slot you can simply pass any arguments to the slot ( a `QString` containing the name of the device ? a `Q_ENUM` ? ..)

Comment: Thanks how would I emit then the signal? Would I do emit connected(this) within the device connection class?

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention that so i have edited my answer.